# import data and then split into array form

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment

I want to split the string into part eg: en, wikipedia, org, wiki, hostname... then check whether those split string appear in the A11. However, I am facing problem when I used `importdata`.

```
str = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';
split_URL = regexp(str,'[:/.]*','split') %// note the different search string
A11 = 'hostname From wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to: navigation, search In    computer networking, a hostname (archaically nodename .....';
feature11 = (~cellfun('isempty', regexpi(A11, split_URL, 'once')))
```

I replaced `str = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';` with `data=importdata(urlq)`, whereas `urlq` contain `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname` which I saved in the note pad.
How do I use the `importdata` in this case?

I can split the `str = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/hostname';` in to array form with 1x6cells but I cannot do so when using `importdata`. Any ideas?

Comment: Since you know how to do with an ordinary string, why does it not work with a string from importdata. Is the data imported correctly? How does it look? Have you tried to debug the script with the debugger?

Comment: Try this - `data=char(importdata(urlq))`

Comment: I got import the data properly, I have solved it with data=char(importdata('urlq')). 
@Divakar, thx~